# React-Redux is creating store states for each reducer function. Why? And how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two reducers currently and for some reason when I console log state I have two copies of state, one for each reducer. Additionally, there is no "main state" or anything. This cannot be right here and I'd like to figure out how to fix it.

I've tried taking `initialState` in and out of `combineReducers` and in and out of my reducers. No matter what I try, within my currently limited Redux knowledge, I get two states.

startReducer.js

```
import initialState from '../initialState'
import {START} from '../constants/actionTypes'

export default function reducer(state=initialState, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case START:{
      return {...state, started:true}
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import start from './startReducer'
import move from './moveReducer'


export default combineReducers({
  move: move,
  start: start
})
```

App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state from inside mapStateToProps: ", {...state})
  return {
    //I WANT to just be saying state.currentPlayer... Why two states?
    currentPlayer: state.move.currentPlayer,
    error: state.move.error,
    gameOver: state.move.gameOver,
    moves: state.move.moves,
    started: state.move.started
  }};
```

The issue here is that when I console log

```
console.log("Full State: ", store.getState())
```

I get this:

```
>move:
  currentPlayer: "white"
  error: null
  gameOver: false
  moves: []
  started: false

>start:
  currentPlayer: "white"
  error: null
  gameOver: false
  moves: []
  started: false
```

Two copies of my state for each reducer. How can I avoid this? What did I do wrong in my architecture that ended me up this way?

Comment: I have no errors of any kind. It just seems massively clumsy to me, at first glance, to have to say ```state.move.moves```.

Comment: @claytongroth just wrote you an answer! Let me know if that's helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initiating `combineReducers()` right away without using `createStore()` from redux. You need `createStore()` to centralize all your reducers into a singular store/redux-state object.

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import start from './startReducer'
import move from './moveReducer'

export default createStore(combineReducers({
  move: move,
  start: start
}))
```

Comment: I currently have a separate ```store.js``` file that just goes ```export default createStore(reducer, middleware )``` Should I combine the logic of these two files somehow then? I thought I was already getting that by saying: ```import reducer from './reducers';``` in my store.js file...

Comment: exactly, insert your logic for combineReducers inside that createStore file. Pass your combineReducers code as the first argument.

Comment: Worked. I just combined them both! Thanks a bunch.